# Error when trying to knit related to lavaan

Tags: r-lavaan

I'm getting this error message when trying to knit. Any suggestions?

Quitting from lines 25-90 [unnamed-chunk-1] (Week-4-Assignment_KK.Rmd)

Error in `if (categorical.flag) ...`:
! argument is of length zero
Backtrace:

1. rmarkdown::render(...)
2. knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
3. knitr:::process_file(text, output)
4. knitr:::process_group.block(group)
5. knitr:::call_block(x)
   ...
6. evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
7. knitr (local) value_fun(ev$value, ev$visible)
8. knitr (local) fun(x, options = options)
9. rmarkdown:::knit_print.data.frame(x, ...)
10. lavaan:::print.lavaan.parameterEstimates(x)
    Execution halted

This is the code in the chunk where it stops:

```
options(repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/")
install.packages("psych")
install.packages("semTools")
install.packages("Amelia")
install.packages("lavaan")
library(psych)
library(semTools)
library(Amelia)
library(lavaan)
data(bfi)

edu3 <- bfi[which(bfi$education == 3),] #only include people with edu = 3
bfi_new <- edu3[, 1:25] #removes all the non BFI item

#define model and order ordinal variables
cfa_mod<-'
F1=~E1+E2+E3+E4+E5
F2=~N1+N2+N3+N4+N5
F3=~C1+C2+C3+C4+C5
F4=~O1+O2+O3+O4+O5
F5=~A1+A2+A3+A4+A5
'

#do MI after specify SE to be robust and specify ordinal data
out <- cfa.mi(cfa_mod, data = bfi_new, m = 20, seed = 712, se="robust",
               miArgs = list(ordered=c("E1","E2","E3","E4","E5",
                                       "N1","N2","N3","N4","N5",
                                       "O1","O2","O3","O4","O5",
                                       "C1","C2","C3","C4","C5",
                                       "A1","A2","A3","A4","A5")))

#run CFA
summary(out,fit=T, pool = TRUE)
fit <- cfa(cfa_mod, bfi_new)
summary(fit,standardize=T) 

  
  #RMSEA                                          0.076
      #this RSMEA indicates good model fit
  #Confidence interval - lower                    0.073
      #upper bound should ideally be <.05 to indicate good fit, this does not indicate good        fit
  #Confidence interval - upper                    0.079
      #upper bound should ideally be <.08 to indicate good fit, so this is a good fit
  #P-value H_0: RMSEA <= 0.05                     0.000
  #SRMR                                           0.076
      #Since the value is <.08, the model demonstrates acceptable fit
  #Comparative Fit Index (CFI)                    0.773
    #CFI should ideally be >.9, so this does not indicate strong model fit
  #Tucker-Lewis Index (TLI)                       0.743
    #TLI should ideally be >.9, so this does not indicate strong model fit

  #Model test
    #Test statistic                              2194.264
    #Degrees of freedom                               265
    #P-value                                        0.000

  #Baseline test
    #Test statistic                              8803.497
    #Degrees of freedom                               300
    #P-value                                        0.000
      

    #The lower test in the model tests indicates the model is a better fit than the baseline test. P<.001 indicates a statistically significant result in both tests. 35 cases were removed due to missing data.
```

I tried adding the first line above installing packages, uninstalled and reinstalled the packages, restarted R multiple times. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

That error is related to 2 new `attributes()` that `lavaan` added to its custom `data.frame` class for its `parameterEstimates()`, which has been [incorporated into the development version](https://github.com/simsem/semTools/commit/e78b2027ea93194fd9770bba3d7fa8e2b90ee39c) of `semTools`.  You can install that using the `remotes` package:

```
remotes::install_github("simsem/semTools/semTools")
```

Comment: After the update, my code is not working, and I'm getting the same error. I'm using `semTools::sem.mi()`, and it's `summary,lavaan.mi-method` that throws the same `Error in if (categorical.flag) { : argument is of length zero`. Any clues on how to resolve this?